# How to get latest update from remote repository then add and commit my file later?

Tags: git

The case is I want to get latest update from remote repository, so I do `git pull remoteRepository`

Unfortunatelly I got conflict

```
$ git pull live master
git@123.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
From 123.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/git/myweb_live
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
...
...
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

So now I have this on my `git status`

```
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
(fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

        modified:   backend/modules/agent/controllers/file1.php
        modified:   backend/modules/agent/controllers/file2.php
        modified:   backend/modules/agent/controllers/manyfile.php
        modified:   backend/modules/agent/views/agent/file1.php
        modified:   backend/modules/agent/views/agent/manyfile.php

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   backend/runtime/debug/index.data
        both modified:   backend/runtime/logs/app.log
        both modified:   backend/runtime/logs/app.log.1
        both modified:   common/component/ScurityHelper.php
        both modified:   common/models/TbCustomer.php
```

I check `git log` and the latest commit is still different with remote repository.

How I can get latest from remote repository?

So Later I can add and commit file I working on which currently doesn't appear in above list, then push to remote repository, and in other machine I pull without conflict.

If I `git commit` with current status, I think it will conflict when I pull from other machine after I git push. Because the above file is not my file where I'm working on. and I want to add my files where I'm working on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick question are those files are modified by you? You don't need those modification anymore?

Comment: Why do you want to unstage these changes? As I understand it, these are the fixes for your merge conflicts. You want to commit those, as git suggests.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer modified by other team

Comment: @bortdc because I want to `git add file` edited by me later.

if I `git commit -m "message"` with current status I think it will conflict, it is safe when I git push to remote, then in other I `git pull remote`?

Comment: Are the files we see here as modified the files that had merge conflicts that you fixed? In that case, you really want to commit them, otherwise you just have to fix them again later.

Comment: `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then after that finishes, run `git merge` (or `git rebase` if I tell you to do that instead of merge)*. You are currently in the middle of a conflicted merge. You *must* either complete or abort this merge. If you choose to abort the merge, you've done the first part (fetch) but not yet started the second part (merge-or-rebase). You really should not use `git pull` at all, as a beginner: instead, learn to use merge or rebase directly. This will leave you in a much better situation when these fail, which they will (and just did!).

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to handle your situation.

In order to unstage the entire directory you can use the following command.

**Command**

```
git rm --cached -r your_dir
```

Another solution is to reset hard the files if you no longer needed but this command is very dangerous that it will delete all modified files, you should beware of what files you don't need in order to use reset.

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

or

```
git reset your_dir
```

**Another method,**

try to check out that modified folder, that will checkout the latest files from your master origin by replacing the modified files.

```
git checkout your_dir
```